# Изменение функции класса-наследника

Tags: c++

Добрый день. На примере вот этого хочу понять как вносить изменения в функцию класса-наследника.
При вызове класса A должно быть 4, при вызову B должно быть 8, но на выходе в обоих классах 4. Не могу понять как исправить ошибку.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    int calculate()
    {
        return 2 * 2;
    }
    void print()
    {
        cout << calculate() << endl;
    }
};

class B :public A
{
public:
    int calculate()
    {
        return 2 * 2 * 2;
    }
};

void main()
{
    A one;
    one.print();
    B two;
    two.print();
}
```

Comment: Это та самая ситуация, когда ты начал изучать язык, а тебе уже понадобилось то, что обычно изучается чуть позже ?) И можно Вас немного поругать ? Спасибо )

Comment: @isnullxbh, да-да, это оказалось в следующей главе )
давайте

Comment: передумал )) ахах)) ведь вы этот код написали ради примера ?)

Comment: @isnullxbh, ну да, просто чтобы принцип понять)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для исправления ошибки Вы можете в базовом классе объявить функцию `int calculate()` как виртуальную, то есть `virtual int calculate()`.